# Where to find a complete list of products by model number of all major US brands?

Tags: data-request, products

Is there such open database or directory available online?

For example, I would like to find out a list of all Samsung products by model number, I would get:

```
Samsung: UN65KS8500, UN55KS5500, UN95KS00, ....
```

The closest that I can find is [outpan](http://www.outpan.com) but it's for barcodes. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It might be possible to crawl or scrape the US PTO DB (http://www.uspto.gov/trademarks-application-process/search-trademark-database) for each brand, but there are a lot of trademarks for products that don't currently exist; that could make things hard depending on the application.